# HTC One recommended Cyanogenmod ROM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, twrp

I have HTC One (model PN07100 - 801n) which I've unlocked and rooted. However I'm having an issue with booting Cyanogenmod, and the boot screen seems to loop endlessly.  At my last attempt I left for half an hour. I'm using TWRP to install the ROMs, and doing a cache/dalvik cache clean before attempting a reboot.

The Cyanogenmod website lists many roms (not sure which ones apply to my model) and I've tried two;

[image: Cyanogen HTC One Device List]

m7tmo & m7ul.

cm-10.1.3-RC2-m7tmo
cm-10.1.3-RC2-m7ul

NB: I'm on T-mobile but T-mobile in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go here and follow the steps: [Official CyanogenMod thread for HTC One](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2382691)

Download latest version from here: [Official CyanogenMod downloads for HTC One](http://www.get.cm/?device=m7ul)

Regarding your problem, getting stuck in a bootloop may mean that you forgot to flash the kernel(boot.img) or didn't flash it properly. Do that again.

Comment: Thanks for that, running through official instructions I noticed Cyanogenmod suggest using ClockworkMod-Recovery rather than TWRP. It worked and Cyanogenmod boots without problem.